# Change attributes for existing field with Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, primary-key, auto-increment

I imported like 40 tables from MySql database to Access using ODBC driver, because that server will go down for several days and I need to keep my application running. Everything went fine (app accepted new connection to Access database) ***except*** for definition of primary key (each table's first field is named "id", has type Integer and is AutoIncremented, was lost during import.

I tried to write a VBA Sub to restore these settings for imported tables, but it is raising error when trying to set AutoIncrement attribute. This is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database

Public Sub RestorePrimaryKeys()
    Dim db As dao.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Dim tables As dao.TableDefs
    Set tables = db.TableDefs
    Dim table As dao.TableDef
    For Each table In tables
        If table.Name Like "table*" Then
            If table.Indexes.Count = 0 Then
                If table.fields(0).Name = "id" Then
                    Dim field As dao.Field2
                    Set field = table.fields(0)

                    field.Attributes = field.Attributes Or FieldAttributeEnum.dbAutoIncrField
                    'raises "Invalid operation (3219)"

                    Dim pkindex As Index
                    Set pkindex = table.CreateIndex("Primary Key")
                    Dim fields As dao.fields
                    Set fields = pkindex.fields
                    fields.Append field
                    pkindex.Primary = True
                    table.Indexes.Append pkindex
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Well, I could do it manually with table layout editor, but there are as I said about 40 tables. And if I could do it manually, why wouldn't I can with VBA? What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You cannot change data type to autoncrement if table has data even in table layout editor. So, try to delete data, change data type and then import again. That may be tricky - you will need to update all foreign keys

Comment: @SergeyS. Thanks! If I wanted to delete all current data inside the Sub above, which command should I use?

Comment: @SergeyS. I know now: `DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM " & table.Name`

Comment: @SergeyS. But no, the error persists even if the tables are empty... :-(